# Lyx V2.2.2 MacOSX Shortcuts

Tags: lyx, mac, shortcut

I have the shortcut in lyx over MacOSX for opening the preferences binded to *cmd+,* 
I wish to unbind it, as it's too close to *cmd+m* which is the default shortcut for mathmode.
I tried the following:

1. went to Lyx->Preferences -> shortcuts -> function "dialog-show prefs" and there changed the default bind to something else. the shortcut I changed to is working, but still the shortcut *cmd+,* works.
2. I tried just for the sake of checking: changed a different function it's default binding, it worked- meaning it removed the default shortcut and only the new bind is working.
3. tried to change it in the MacOSX preferences: system preferences -> keyboard -> shortcuts -> app shortcuts -> there added Lyx "diaglog-show prefs", and obviously it didn't work.

I'm pretty desperate.
Thank you in advance

EDIT: added picture that might clarify:
in the picture it shows that this bind is somewhat related to the mac-OSX as in the menu it binds to it
[image]

Comment: You might want to take a look at the text configurations of the shortcuts. The GUI is just an interface for editing. To find the text file, go to LyX > About, and copy your "User directory". In your file browser, navigate to that directory and inside, open the directory "bind". In there, there is a file user.bind. Perhaps by looking at the file directly you will be able to figure out what to do. Don't forget to back the file up before changing it. To change it, Exit LyX, then change and save it, then start LyX.

Comment: hey, thanks for the replay. here's the bind file, but unfortunately the shortcut for cmd+, isn't there:  ## This file is automatically generated by lyx
## All modifications will be lost

Format 4

\unbind "C-comma" "dialog-show prefs"
\unbind "C-n" "buffer-new"

\bind "M-S-BackSpace" "language english"
\bind "M-S-h" "language hebrew"
\bind "C-backslash" "dialog-show prefs"
\bind "C-n C-A-S-n" "buffer-new"

Comment: Dang, I'm not sure then. You might want to join the lyx-users mailing list and ask there.